# Adding SATA port to laptop motherboard

Tags: laptop, sata, soldering

I've got Acer Aspire ES 14 ES1-431-C3QT and it has only 32GB eMMC storage but when I dissassembled it I noticed there is space for 2.5'' HDD and something like a port for SATA connection (pic [here](https://postimg.org/image/fkurdf3mb/)).
If I managed to solder some SATA connector (this [thing](https://sc01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB14GFiHFXXXXXJXVXXq6xXFXXXW/222560323/HTB14GFiHFXXXXXJXVXXq6xXFXXXW.jpg) maybe?) and BIOS will support it, is it enough make SATA port work?

It looks quite straight forward but I know nothing about voltages etc. in there.

Comment: Are you sure there's not some connectors already in place on the other side of the board / what the image shows?

Comment: Unfortunately, there are not (https://postimg.org/image/h6xyyslxf/)

Comment: You can't tell whenever the wiring to the needed control is available or whenever the BIOS would support it so even if you soldered there is no telling whenever it would work. In addition it would need some solid soldering skills.